# excel, matching with greater than and lesser than and static values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

I am trying to do in Excel what should be done in a database. I have a spreadsheet with raw data and which I am trying to query based on criteria. Given the following example table:

```
  A    B    C    D    E    F
1 Red  up   1    4    dn   5
2 Blu  up   5    9
3 Yel  dn   1    4
4 Gre  dn   5    9
```

I would like to return the value of column A that meets the criteria of E1 and F1 where E1 is found in column B and F1 is found equal or between the values in columns C and D.  In the example, I would like to return "Gre".

I have been pulling my hair out with INDEX and MATCH functions and I can get part of my task done, but have found nothing extensible to solve the total solution.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Please try this...

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$4,MATCH(1,INDEX(($B$1:$B$4=$E$1)*($C$1:$C$4<=$F$1)*($D$1:$D$4>=$F$1),),0)),"")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind adding headings to your raw data.
[image]

You could use this formula:
`=DGET($A$1:$D$5,"Field 1",$E$1:$F$2)`

**A1:D5** being your database.
**Field 1** is the field to return values from.
**E1:F2** is your criteria (field name and value to look for in that field).

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/DGET-function-455568bf-4eef-45f7-90f0-ec250d00892e

As noted by @Vityata this won't work for the OP - looking for the value 6 would return a `#VALUE` error rather than Gre.

A couple of updates would allow it to work:

- Updating the formula to:  `=DGET($A$1:$D$5,"Field 1",$E$1:$G$2)`
- Updating the table to:
  [image]

The values in F2 and G2 are calculated as: 
`="<=" & $H$2` and `=">=" & $H$2`
This example would then return Yel when 1 is entered in cell H2.

Comment: Nice formula, but I doubt that it would work for the OP - `found equal or between the values in columns C and D.`

Comment: Good point - I missed that in the question.  I'll update to make it work, although that will move away slightly from the exact data format given by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I liked the question, thus I have elaborated a bit on the sktneer's answer.
The reason, it works is because we are looking for truth (a.k.a. `1`) in the following formula:

```
=MATCH(1;
                          INDEX(($B$1:$B$4=$E$1)*($C$1:$C$4<=$F$1)*($D$1:$D$4>=$F$1););0)
```

Like this:
[image]

Then with an INDIRECT we may achieve the answer:
`=INDIRECT(ADDRESSE(I1;1))`

If you want it in one formula, it should be like this:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(
                         MATCH(1;INDEX(($B$1:$B$4=$E$1)*($C$1:$C$4<=$F$1)*($D$1:$D$4>=$F$1););0);
                          1))
```